# near "loop": expecting IF; near "process": expecting LOOP

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

This is the error

- Error: C:/modeltech64_10.5/examples/zarb.vhd(51): near "loop": (vcom-1576) expecting IF.
- Error: C:/modeltech64_10.5/examples/zarb.vhd(56): near "process": (vcom-1576) expecting LOOP.

```vhdl
library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

use IEEE.std_logic_signed.all;

use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity MULT is

GENERIC(n:integer:=4);

 port(A,B: in  std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
       P : out std_logic_vector(2*n-1 downto 0)); -- PRODUCT

end entity;


architecture BOOTH of MULT is

begin

BOOTH:process(A,B)

 variable X:std_logic_vector(2*n downto 0); 

 variable Y:std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0); 

 variable Z:std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0); 

 variable U:std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0); 

begin

for J in 0 to n-1 loop

 U(j):='0';

end loop;

 X:=U & A & '0';

 Y:=B;               
 
for I in 0 to n-1 loop

 if(X(1)='1' and X(0)='0') then

  Z:=X(2*n downto n+1);

   X(2*n downto n+1):= Z-Y;

    X(2*n-1 downto 0):=X(2*n downto 1);


 else if(X(1)='0' and X(0)='1') then

  Z:=X(2*n downto n+1);

   X(2*n downto n+1):= Z+Y;

    x(2*n-1 downto 0):=X(2*n downto 1);


 else

  X(2*n-1 downto 0):=X(2*n downto 1);

end if;

end loop;

P(2*n-1 downto 0) <= X(2*n downto 1);


end process;

end architecture BOOTH;
```

Comment: [Using a consistent whitespace format can demonstrate where the error lies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rCrr.jpg).

Comment: Subtracting or Adding Y as signed values causes sign extension for an ALU with 2 * N - 1 bits. Your Booth Multiplier works (and [the signed arithmetic allows a multiply of the most negative values of A and B to give the right answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MJ0U.jpg)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to understand what the compiler is telling you here. At the `end loop` it was expecting an `end if`. That means that you are actually inside another `if` when you try to close your `loop`. The next error is just a consequence of the first.

Why is that so?

Let's check where the starts of the blocks in question could possibly be. At the `end if` above the `end loop`, you are obviously closing one `if` successfully, yet you are still inside another one, according to the compiler. You *think* you close the `if(X(1)='1' and X(0)='0') then`, but obviously you don't, otherwise we wouldn't have that error.

Is there another `if` between that one and the `end if`? **Yes!** It is in this line: `else if(X(1)='0' and X(0)='1') then`.

You obviously thought that this counts as part of the original `if`, but the compiler thinks otherwise, so that's the point where you would google `else if vhdl`. You would then find that the correct syntax is actually `elsif`, because otherwise you do `else` plus a new, separate `if` inside of the `else`, which is what happened here.

To visualize what happened, by using the indentation that would match what the compiler sees right now:

```vhdl
for I in 0 to n-1 loop
 if(X(1)='1' and X(0)='0') then
   ...
 else
   if(X(1)='0' and X(0)='1') then
    ...
   else
    ...
   end if;
 ??? (end if missing here)
end loop; <<< error, end if expected, end loop found
```

With `elsif`, it would be like this instead:

```vhdl
for I in 0 to n-1 loop
 if(X(1)='1' and X(0)='0') then
   ...
 elsif(X(1)='0' and X(0)='1') then
  ...
 else
  ...
 end if;
end loop;
```

Bottom line: You need `elsif` instead of `else if`.

*By the way: Your indentation makes no sense. You have subsequent lines always indented one space further, even though they are on the same block level. This is only going to confuse you. Make sure you indent your code properly - there are also [editor plugins](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vinrobot.vhdl-formatter) out there that can help you with that.*